# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Login and Register form on same page

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have both Login form and Register form on the same page, I tried like this:

```
@model Project.Models.LoginModel
@model Project.Models.RegisterModel

// Login form
...

// Register form
...
```

...but I can only have one model reference at the top of the View. I tried with partial views for both forms, but then the functionality was lost.

Any ideas on how to get this right? Thanks!

Comment: Here you can get a more detailed answer if you're in need:

[Login form and Register form on the same page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17860676/1791760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use only one model in a view, create your viewModel class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

and import it in your view

```
@model Project.Models.ViewModel
```

Comment: thats the classic way. fast typing @AliRızaAdıyahşi

Comment: Btw it should be public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }

Thanks :)